# Why does the GitHub actions ssh login not set my environment variable?

Tags: ssh, terminal, environment-variables

When I login using ssh command to remote server `Linux VM-0-16-centos 3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 10 13:32:12 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and execute `env` command, I can find the following environment variable:

```
ENV=TENCENT
```

But when I login through GitHub Actions like this:

```
- name: Restart server
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.BINGQIAN_HOST }}
    username: ${{ secrets.BINGQIAN_USER }}
    password: ${{ secrets.SSH_BINGQIAN_PASSWORD }}
    script: |
      cd /opt/apps/pydolphin
      nohup /opt/apps/pydolphin/tencent-cloud-start-app.sh &> schedule.log &!
      sleep 20
```

It could not find the environmnet config `ENV=TENCENT`, what the difference between the two ways to login? I am using the same user to login. I set the env in `.zshrc` like this:

```
export ENV=TENCENT
```

Comment: The first probably starts a login shell that reads your configs, the second one does not

Comment: Can you explain what part of your manual ssh session sets the `ENV` environment variable?  If it's set by the software that's connecting to your remote server, then it looks like your Github Actions config does not duplicate that behavior.  If it's set by some script or command that happens in the remote server, will that script/command recognize the connections from Github Actions needs to have the same setting as your manual ssh connections?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a zsh expert, but I found this reference in the `zsh` man page:

> If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from /etc/zprofile and then $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile.  Then, if the shell is interactive, commands are read from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc.

There's more both before and after that part, and another part of the man page indicates that `$ZDOTDIR` defaults to the user's home dir.

The essence is that when the login session is not interactive, the zsh shell will not invoke the commands in the `~/.zshrc` file.  Your manual ssh connections are interactive and the ones from Github Actions are not interactive, so the command to set the `ENV` variable is not invoked when Github Actions makes the connection.